# Ignoring CSS margins for embedded DIVs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a classic bootstrap template, like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    ...header...
      <div class="carouselContainer">
      ...carousel...
      </div>
    ...content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and now my website looks like this (H - header, S - slider, C - content, F - footer, with margin: auto):

[image]

I want to (visually, using CSS) pull out slider from div.row and div.col-12, like this.

[image]

I have tried using position:absolute, but after that, part of content is hidden under slider, plus I want to keep everything safe on different screen resolutions (not using pixels, and maybe on smallest screens carousel will be hidden).

does anyone have an idea how to do it? (I'm sorry if I complicated.)

Comment: why not change the HTML structure and use a container-fluid to wrap your slider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simply stacking different `.containers`, like this...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    ...header...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="carouselContainer">
      ...carousel...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    ...content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You **shouldn't** nest `.container`'s but you can stack them! In this case `container-fluid` will go full width. the others won't.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the HTML structure and use a container-fluid to wrap your slider.

It would be better ( imho ) to use HTML tags for elements like `<header>` `<main>` `<footer>`

So a structure would be

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
     <nav>
       Nav here
     </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="slider">
          Slider Here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container content">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
         Content Here
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer Here
</footer>
```

Comment: I think you need more divs.

Comment: @Rob You need as many as you need :) . I don't know if you were sarcastic or not but yes, in a ' real ' environment you would need more divs